# How do I add a table row to a table after the forth <tr> using Javascript and or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, element

How do I add a table row to a table after the forth table row using Javascript and or jQuery?

Comment: What have you tried?  jQuery provides lots of functions for manipulating DOM objects.  Did you make any attempt at using them?  What didn't work?

Comment: Usually, you would do it with a combination of HTML and Javascript. Also, when asking a question, here, one usually includes where they've started, with code, as we're not here to write it for you.

Comment: Learn to use w3cschool and jquery.com as resource try a few moves before posting your question, people prefer correcting your code rather than writing it for your :) **Tip: nth-child(n) also works fine but leave the code to yourself**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$('table tr:eq(3)').after('<tr><td>5</td></tr>');
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/nUEy7/)</kbd>

---

or

[.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

```
$('<tr><td>5</td></tr>').insertAfter('table tr:eq(3)');
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/nUEy7/1)</kbd>